# how to extract a column in a for loop out of a dataframe from multiple list glob created by glob

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, glob

I am a beginner in Python and just started with machine learning. I can not figure out how to extract a column out of df_test.

I would like to extract column 280 (this is the target y for a linearregression, y_test)

I used glob, to combine multiple cvs files, which are the test set for the regression.  I have to extract x_test which is columns 0-279 and all rows. and y_test column 280

```
from glob import glob
filenames= glob('webStats_test*.csv')
df_test= [pd.read_csv(f)for f in filenames]
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

really hope you could help, already spend ours looking and trying but with no results.

Kind regards irmgard

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas .iloc for this.

```
x_test = new_df.iloc[:, :280]
y_test = new_df.iloc[:, 280]
```

But in your code, you still first have to fill new_df with actual data... I would append all your different files to a list of DataFrames and then use concat to combine the list of DataFrames to 1 DataFrame.